# Sites one page aparecem em buscadores?

Tags: algoritmo-de-busca, parallax, seo, single-page-application

Sites One page, são listados normalmente em buscadores?

Existem diversos artigos e parece que sites One page não são muito amigáveis para buscadores, isto é uma realidade? Em quais casos? Somente em conteúdo entregue por Ajax?

Penso em montar um "cartão online" para o cliente, com conteúdo bem resumido, usando efeito parallax, listando apenas algumas formas de contato.

Usando como exemplo este site abaixo, o que eu devo fazer para melhorar o resultado de buscas?

http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/

Considerando que este site seria apenas um portfólio, e one page ou não teria o mesmo conteúdo;

Resumindo: 
Um one page com 4 sections, ligados por anchor links tem menos eficiência de busca contra um site com 4 páginas com uma section dentro de cada?

Comment: Seu site usa ajax? A questão não é ser one-page ou utilizar o efeito x ou y. Se o conteúdo que precisa ser indexado está contido no HTML que seu server entrega, os buscadores enxergam. Se vem por ajax, eles geralmente não enxergam e você precisa usar técnicas específicas para "conversar" com eles.

Comment: Então o site irá indexar normalmente, aparecer em buscas normalmente?

Comment: Se estiver tudo sendo servido junto, será indexado sim. Agora, se vai indexar links de seções e levar para as seções corretas, depende da sua programação. Recomendo você testar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

Sim, sites de uma única página aparecem em buscadores, mas em geral é necessário um grande esforço adicional para isso.

## Páginas tradicionais x dinâmicas

Os buscadores indexam vários tipos de conteúdo, principalmente HTML, que é a base da web tradicional.

Isso significa que se o conteúdo não estiver prontamente disponível no código HTML ele não ai adivinhar onde está, nem vai interpretar seus scripts e saber qual conteúdo você pode carregar dinamicamente.

## Técnicas alternativas

Para resolver esse problema, existem algumas técnicas que podem ser usadas:

1. Incluir todo o conteúdo dinâmico oculto no HTML de forma que o usuário não veja, mas o robô indexador sim. Dessa forma a navegação no site consiste em alternar a visibilidade dos elementos.
2. Mostrar uma página alternativa para os buscadores. É possível identificar se um robô indexador está lendo seu site através dos cabeçalhos HTTP. Você pode configurar o Apache ou qualquer servidor web para exibir uma página em HTML puro para ele com todo o conteúdo do site.
3. Usar um *site map* e criar várias URLs alternativas que renderizam o respectivo conteúdo, entretanto se o usuário acessar uma delas ele então é redirecionado para a aplicação principal.

**Nota:** não pretendi ser exaustivo. Podem haver inúmeras outras técnicas.

## Conclusão

É perfeitamente possível otimizar um *Single Page Application* para SEO, mas leve o esforço adicional em conta antes de adotar uma solução como essa.

Particularmente, para a web em geral eu prefero um modelo tradicional com páginas separadas.